# PyMongo: TypeError: spec must be an instance of dict

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a list of MongoDB ids

```
id_list = [{u'_id': u'0'}, {u'_id': u'1'}, {u'_id': u'2'}, {u'_id': u'3'}, {u'_id': u'4'}]
```

And I want to fire a single query to MongoDB and get the matching documents back in the same order as the list.
However, the below code caused `TypeError: spec must be an instance of dict`.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = MongoClient()

    sDB = db.test.users
    id_list = [{u'_id': u'0'}, {u'_id': u'1'}, {u'_id': u'2'}, {u'_id': u'3'}, {u'_id': u'4'}]
    print list(sDB.find(id_list[0:2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo query syntax must be used, i.e.:

```
collection.find({"_id": {"$in": [id1, id2, ..., idN]}})
```

To respect it, first get a list of only needed ids, not a list of dicts:

```
needed_ids_only = map(lambda x: x['_id'], id_list[0:2])
# needed_ids_only is now == [u'0', u'1']
```

Then, provide it to "$in" operator:

```
print list(sDB.find({"_id": {"$in": needed_ids_only}}))
```

Worth to mention, that if `_id` of your documents is a string, as you've mention in question, all is ok. But if you mean an ObjectId, then it is needed to convert to it also before querying.

So, if you documents looks like this:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    _id: '0',
    // ...
},
{
    _id: '1',
    // ...
},
// ...
```

Then all is ok. But if they looks like this:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    _id: ObjectId('0'),
    // ...
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('1'),
    // ...
},
// ...
```

Then it is needed to convert _id values to ObjectId:

```
from bson import ObjectId
needed_ids_only = map(lambda x: ObjectId(x['_id']), id_list[0:2])
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses dictionary for searching and you are providing an array:

Your example:

```
id_list[0:2] is [{u'_id': u'0'}, {u'_id': u'1'}]
```

instead you can use `$in` for this:

```
db.test.users.find({'_id':{'$in': ["0", "1", "2"]}})
```